# IE. Open fileUpload via JS and do form.Submit()

Tags: file, internet-explorer, upload

I have a FileUpload on my page. Our site has similar design for all buttons and textboxes. As far as I know we can't change the style of "Browse..." button in fileUpload. That's why I have to customize the FileUpload. I have textbox, our custom "Browse..." button and hidden FileUpload. When user clicks our custom "Browse..." button I call JQuery function which simulate the FileUpload click:

```
browseButton.click(function (){
    fileUpload.click();
});
```

Everything is OK in all browsers except IE! I get "SCRIPT5: Access is denied." on form.Submit(). I have already read some articles where people wrote that we can create a Label which will replace the "Browse..." button for IE. But I must use only our customized buttons. Is it possible to solve this problem?

Comment: No, now we display a common FileUpload for IE. There is similar problem for Safari and you can fix it by setting the styles of hidden FileUpload like that - .hiddenFileUpload { opacity: 0; z-index: 100; /*for safari*/}